# Fatal error: Failed opening required file

Tags: commerce

I am quite new in Drupal. When installing Kickstart module in a Acquia based Drupal 7 setup on a localhost, I got this message. I looked on the internet and saw a lot of answers, but it didn't help me. It seems the plugins.inc file is fine, but I can't do anything now.

> Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/Users/aztem/Sites/acquia-drupal/sites/all/modules/panels/plugins/export_ui/panels_layouts.inc' (include_path='.:/Applications/acquia-drupal/common/pear:/usr/lib/php') in /Users/aztem/Sites/acquia-drupal/sites/all/modules/commerce_kickstart/modules/contrib/ctools/includes/plugins.inc on line 475

Answer (score -1):

Commerce Kickstart isn't a module, it's an installation profile. If you want to add Commerce to your site, try install using drush, or just load all the modules manually.

drush dl commerce

Using the drush command will install Ubercart essentially, and you can setup commerce that way.

Comment: I already installed Kickstart in one package into the sites/all/modules but will take it out and put in one by one to see what happens.

Comment: /Users/aztem/Sites/acquia-drupal/ **sites/all/modules**/commerce_kickstart/ **modules/contrib**/ctools/includes/plugins.inc

This is an incorrect installation. You can't just drop Commerce Kickstart profile into sites/all/modules. Like I said, it's a **profile**, not a module. 

I made a screencast (link below) that should help you understand how to install commerce on your existing Acquia site.

(http://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/cll6j1VhIz)